# How to set the buttons label text color for state UIControlStateHighlighted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am creating an iPhone application in which i have a custom button. i have set the buttons title by creating a Label and adding it as subview. now when the button is highlighted i want to change the labels text color.

here is my code,

```
UIButton *button1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(68,162, 635, 101)];    
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startwithouttext.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startactivewithouttext.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

   UILabel *buttonLabel = [[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(button1.bounds.origin.x+50, button1.bounds.origin.y+20, button1.bounds.size.width-100, button1.bounds.size.height-40)];

    [buttonLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:28]];
    buttonLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    buttonLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:83.0/255.0 green:83.0/255.0 blue:83.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    buttonLabel.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    buttonLabel.text = @"Long text string";
    [button1 addSubview:buttonLabel];
    [button1 bringSubviewToFront:buttonLabel];
    [button1 setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
    [button1 setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1clicked:) forControlEvents:

[mainView button1];
```

can any body help me to change the text color when the button is highlighted?

Comment: i can change the text color when the button1clicked method is called, but what i want is to change the text color when button is highlihted

Comment: what do you mean by " when the button is highlighted i want to change the labels text color " ? did you mean when button is clicked and after the click text should be as it was ?

Comment: that is for UIControlStateHighlighted i want to change the text color. if you hover over the button at that time i want to change the text color

Answer (score 22):

Found the answer in a different question on StackOverflow:
[UIButton color issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909637/uibutton-color-issues)

```
[button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This is if you can work without creating a Label and adding it as subview as you mention above.

Comment: This will only work if you set both colors in different state, or text color of every state will become red.

Answer (score 10):

you can add target for `UIControlStateHighlighted` state of `UIButton` like

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHighlighted:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

and in `buttonHighlighted` method you can change the color of your label's text

```
- (void) buttonHighlighted:(id)sender
{
  //code here
}
```

Hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: why dont you use UIButton's text label ? why are you adding another label on button ?

Comment: I am using custom Button. in that i have white background for UIcontrolstatenormal and pink background for UIcontrolstateHighlighted. thats y i am not using Uibuttons text label. i have another problem that is after clicking the button its background comes to the white and the text's are hidden because of white colour. can u post me sample code for how to use Uibuttons text label for custom buttons

Answer (score 1):

For SelectedColor

```
[yourButton setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

For HighlightedColor

```
[yourButton setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```