# In iOS 7, how do I change the color of the options in my UIActionSheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiactionsheet

I use green as the "action color" throughout my app, and I want the options in my UIActionSheets to be green as well, for consistency. How can I change the colour of the UIActionSheet options to green from blue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Utilize the `willPresentActionSheet` delegate method of `UIActionSheet` to change the action sheet button color.

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is better. Uses a delegate method not to mention more concise. Also the above answer doesn't change the cancel button's color.

Comment: For some reason, if you also want to change the font, you have to do that before changing the color, or it won't work

Comment: @BrenoGazzola: What happens?

Comment: When doing `button.titleLabel.textColor = MY_COLOR;button.titleLabel.font = MY_FONT;` the options were changed to the new font but remained blue and red. Simply changing the order to `button.titleLabel.font = MY_FONT;button.titleLabel.textColor = MY_COLOR;` fixed the problem and I got both the new font and new colors.

Comment: That is strange. Which version of iOS are you running and what device/simulator are you using to run the code? If I can replicate this tonight, I'll submit a bug ticket to apple.

Comment: don't forget to set the button's color for selected states as well! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806840/how-to-set-the-buttons-label-text-color-for-state-uicontrolstatehighlighted

Regular buttons will use UIControlStateHighlighted when tapped, but the Cancel button will use UIControlStateSelected

Answer (score 18):

You could do something like this:

```
// Your code to instantiate the UIActionSheet
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
// Configure actionSheet

// Iterate through the sub views of the action sheet
for (id actionSheetSubview in actionSheet.subviews) {
    // Change the font color if the sub view is a UIButton
    if ([actionSheetSubview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)actionSheetSubview;
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    }
}
```

If you're going to reuse this a lot, I'd subclass UIActionSheet and use this code.

Comment: Is that using private APIs?

Comment: No, it is just accessing all the subviews of a UIActionSheet and finding the buttons

Comment: When you tap it it changes back to blue.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work for the cancel button ? Mine keep geting it's previous color

Answer (score 0):

You can change easily the application's tint color using this short function on your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Hope it will help you :)