# UILabel doesn't dim with button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

I have a programmatically generated UIButton with a label property and a background image. When tapped the background image becomes grey but the text does not. How do I make the label also indicate when it is being tapped?

As requested, my button code:

```
#import "BCB.h"
@implementation BCB
@synthesize cardText;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setFrame:frame];
        cardText = cardText = [[MyLabel alloc]
                               initWithFrame:(CGRect){8, 8, 144, 186}];
        cardText.numberOfLines = 0;
        cardText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0];
        cardText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cardText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cardText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [self addSubview:cardText];
        [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BC" ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And the MyLabel code:

```
#import "MyLabel.h"
@implementation MyLabel
// Helper function to actually set the text.
- (void)reallySetText:(NSString*)text
{
    [super setText:text];
}
// Function to top align text within a label.
- (void)topAlign
{
    // Get the size of the text box containing the label with its current font and size.
    CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font
                            constrainedToSize:(CGSize){self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height}
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    // Trim the frame up to exactly fit the text.
    self.frame = (CGRect){self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, textSize.width, textSize.height};
}
// Shrink font until it fits the provided frame.
CGFloat maxSizeThatFitsFrame(MyLabel* labelCopy, CGFloat fontSize, CGRect rect)
{
    while (labelCopy.frame.size.height > rect.size.height && fontSize > 4.0f)
    {
        fontSize -= 0.5f;
        labelCopy.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];
        [labelCopy topAlign];
    }
    return fontSize;
}
// Overloading the drawTextInRect method to topAlign the text as well.
-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
    [self topAlign];
}
// Function to set the label to have the provided text within the provided rectangle with the provided initial font size.
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text inFrame:(CGRect)rect withFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize andColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    // Set the text.
    [super setText:text];
    // Set the frame.
    [self setFrame:rect];
    // Make a copy of the label.
    MyLabel* labelCopy = [[MyLabel alloc]
                          initWithFrame:
                          (CGRect){
                              self.frame.origin.x,
                              self.frame.origin.y,
                              self.frame.size.width,
                              self.frame.size.height+240}];
    // Make the text wrap properly.
    labelCopy.numberOfLines = 0;
    labelCopy.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    // Set the copy's text.
    [labelCopy reallySetText:self.text];
    // Set the copy's font.
    labelCopy.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];
    // Top align the copy.
    [labelCopy topAlign];
    // If the copy's height is larger than the rectangle's height, resize it until it fits.
    if (labelCopy.frame.size.height > rect.size.height)
    {
        fontSize = maxSizeThatFitsFrame(labelCopy, fontSize, rect);
    }
    // Set the label's font to a size that fits.
    [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];
    // Set the label's color.
    self.textColor = color;
    // Make the text wrap properly.
    self.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    // Top align the label.
    [self topAlign];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `setTitleColor:forState:` for `UIControlStateHighlighted`. [Docs.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor%3aforState%3a)

Comment: Will this method work when the title is **not** set by `[button setTitle:]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these two similar questions. They are sure to solve your queries :

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806840/how-to-set-the-buttons-label-text-color-for-state-uicontrolstatehighlighted)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909637/uibutton-color-issues)

Here's one thing to try :

you can add target for `UIControlStateHighlighted` state of `UIButton` like

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHighlighted:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

and in `buttonHighlighted` method you can change the color of your label's text

```
- (void) buttonHighlighted:(id)sender 
{
  //code to change the color of your Label subview...  
}
```

Hope this helps