# Highlight entire UIButton, not only image at the left side?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a usual UIButton with an image at the left side. Show touch on highlight is turned on in storyboard, but when I touch this button, the image gets highlighted and the text doesn't! I would like to highlight the entire UIButton.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909637/uibutton-color-issues

Comment: @Krish, Thanks for reply, but the question you are pointing at is regarding text _color_, but I mean text _highlight_ (that white cloud around an arrow on the screenshot).

Comment: Can you programmatically add this line of code to your button?
`button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = TRUE;`

Comment: @Andriko13 , thank you, but that doesn't help - only arrow glows.

Comment: Is 'back'/'nazad' the title of the UIButton?

Comment: @Andriko13, Yes, it is (НАЗАД is BACK).

Comment: The text is part of image? I mean its complete image with text and arrow or the text and arrow you are adding via title with a background image?

Comment: @NewStackUser , I'm adding via title and Image, not Background Image. Like this: http://monosnap.com/image/uFGcLTlo4WmtJUJY4iTUMYUTLXSM9k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the image as "background image" and the title as it is , now select  the option "Shows Touch On Highlight". Hope this help and will highlight the complete button.

Comment: Thanks, marked as "best answer". But besides setting background I had to make custom UIButton class and redefine "backgroundRectForBounds" method - without it arrow had size of the entire button(stretched to enermous size).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. A workaround is to change the title color for the highlighted state.

Two solutions :

**1/ In the Interface Builder :**

- in your UIButton property, for "**state config**" property, select "**highlighted**"
- Change the text color property to the highlighted color you want.

[image]

**2/ Programmatically :**

Same idea as above , in **Swift 3** you would do :

```
button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .highlighted)
```